# JS + HTML + CSS Rock Paper Scissors game not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a rock-paper-scissors game. Everything works correctly (the buttons work fine, and also the keypress events) however when you choose rock/paper/scissors, it doesn't play the game. It can send a console message (if you code it) but the game doesn't works.

```js
//yes
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
let gameStart = false
let userchoice;
let userwin = 0
let pcchoice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)
var pcchoice = choices[pcchoice1]
let pcwin = 0
//yes


// TODO checks if user won or not
function win(userchoice, pcchoice) {
  if (userchoice == "rock") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
  }

  if (userchoice == "paper") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
  }

  if (userchoice == "scissors") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
  }
}


// TODO hiding elements
function hide(x, y) {
  var x = document.getElementById(y)
  x.style.display = "none"
}

// TODO unhiding elements
function show(x, y) {
  var x = document.getElementById(y)
  x.style.display = "block"
}

// TODO hides elements at start
window.onload = () => {
  hide(back, "back"), hide(rock, "rock"), hide(paper, "paper"), hide(scissors, "scissors"), hide(ChooseAnOption, "ChooseAnOption"), hide(r, "r"), hide(p, "p"), hide(s, "s")
}


// TODO play button functions
document.getElementById("play").onclick = () => {
  hide(info, "info"), hide(title, "title"), hide(play, "play")
  show(ChooseAnOption, "ChooseAnOption"), show(r, "r"), show(p, "p"), show(s, "s")

  gameStart = true

  // TODO keyboard keys
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (gameStart == true) {
      if (event.key === "r") {
        userchoice = "rock"
        console.log("rock")
      }
      if (event.key === "p") {
        userchoice = "paper"
        console.log("paper")
      }
      if (event.key === "s") {
        userchoice = "scissors"
        console.log("scissors")
      }
    }
  })

  // TODO game loop
  win(userchoice, pcchoice)
}

// TODO info button functions
document.getElementById("info").onclick = () => {
  hide(info, "info"), hide(title, "title"), hide(play, "play")
  show(back, "back"), show(rock, "rock"), show(paper, "paper"), show(scissors, "scissors")
}

// TODO back button functions
document.getElementById("back").onclick = () => {
  hide(back, "back"), hide(rock, "rock"), hide(paper, "paper"), hide(scissors, "scissors")
  show(info, "info"), show(title, "title"), show(play, "play")
}

// TODO rock
document.getElementById("r").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "rock"
  console.log("rock")
}

// TODO paper
document.getElementById("p").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "paper"
  console.log("paper")
}

// TODO scissors
document.getElementById("s").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "scissors"
  console.log("scissors")
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
}

button {
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(0.82);
  background-color: rgba(156, 29, 29, 0.74);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#f7ce5e">
  <center>
    <h1 id="title"><br>Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors!</h1>

    <button class="button" id="play">Play</button><button class="button" id="info">Info</button>


    <center><button class="button" id="back">< Back</button>
      <p class="p" id="rock"><br>Rock: Can beat Scissors. <br>Loses to Paper.</p>
      <p class="p" id="paper"><br>Paper: Can beat Rock. <br>Loses to Scissors.</p>
      <p class="p" id="scissors"><br>Scissors: Can beat paper. <br>Loses to Rock.</p>


      <p class="p" id="ChooseAnOption">Choose an Option (you can use keyboard keys)</p>
      <button class="button" id="r">Rock (R)</button><button class="button" id="p">Paper (P)</button><button class="button" id="s">Scissors (S)</button></center>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems that your game loop implementation is wrong. Try to check on that.

Comment: Your `onclick` functions just log the user's choice, they never call `win()`.

Comment: the handlers for clicks on the buttons just set a variable and then `console.log`. They don't do anything else.

Comment: And you only set `pcchoice` once, when the game starts. The computer has to make a new choice each time the player does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not call `win` after `userchoice` set. You can check the full implementation which I embedded all events with `win` calls as well as `randomizePCChoice` calls (to randomize PC choice)

```js
//yes
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
let gameStart = false
let userchoice;
let userwin = 0
let pcwin = 0
//yes

//adding a new function to randomize PC choice
function randomizePCChoice() {
  let pcchoice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)
  var pcchoice = choices[pcchoice1]
  return pcchoice
}

// TODO checks if user won or not
function win(userchoice, pcchoice) {

  if (userchoice == "rock") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
  }

  if (userchoice == "paper") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
  }

  if (userchoice == "scissors") {
    if (pcchoice == "rock") {
      alert("PC won!")
      pcwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "paper") {
      alert("User won!")
      userwin += 1
    }
    if (pcchoice == "scissors") {
      alert("Both equal!")
    }
  }
}


// TODO hiding elements
function hide(x, y) {
  var x = document.getElementById(y)
  x.style.display = "none"
}

// TODO unhiding elements
function show(x, y) {
  var x = document.getElementById(y)
  x.style.display = "block"
}

// TODO hides elements at start
window.onload = () => {
  hide(back, "back"), hide(rock, "rock"), hide(paper, "paper"), hide(scissors, "scissors"), hide(ChooseAnOption, "ChooseAnOption"), hide(r, "r"), hide(p, "p"), hide(s, "s")
}


// TODO play button functions
document.getElementById("play").onclick = () => {
  hide(info, "info"), hide(title, "title"), hide(play, "play")
  show(ChooseAnOption, "ChooseAnOption"), show(r, "r"), show(p, "p"), show(s, "s")

  gameStart = true

  // TODO keyboard keys
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (gameStart == true) {
      if (event.key === "r") {
        userchoice = "rock"
        console.log("rock")
      }
      if (event.key === "p") {
        userchoice = "paper"
        console.log("paper")
      }
      if (event.key === "s") {
        userchoice = "scissors"
        console.log("scissors")
      }
      //after user choice, we randomize PC choice
      const pcchoice = randomizePCChoice()
      //check who wins
      win(userchoice, pcchoice)
    }
  })

  // TODO game loop
  //win(userchoice, pcchoice) //this call is not applied correctly
}

// TODO info button functions
document.getElementById("info").onclick = () => {
  hide(info, "info"), hide(title, "title"), hide(play, "play")
  show(back, "back"), show(rock, "rock"), show(paper, "paper"), show(scissors, "scissors")
}

// TODO back button functions
document.getElementById("back").onclick = () => {
  hide(back, "back"), hide(rock, "rock"), hide(paper, "paper"), hide(scissors, "scissors")
  show(info, "info"), show(title, "title"), show(play, "play")
}

// TODO rock
document.getElementById("r").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "rock"
  //after user choice, we randomize PC choice
  const pcchoice = randomizePCChoice()
  //check who wins
  win(userchoice, pcchoice)
  console.log("rock")
}

// TODO paper
document.getElementById("p").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "paper"
  //after user choice, we randomize PC choice
  const pcchoice = randomizePCChoice()
  //check who wins
  win(userchoice, pcchoice)
  console.log("paper")
}

// TODO scissors
document.getElementById("s").onclick = () => {
  userchoice = "scissors"
  //after user choice, we randomize PC choice
  const pcchoice = randomizePCChoice()
  //check who wins
  win(userchoice, pcchoice)
  console.log("scissors")
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
}

button {
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(0.82);
  background-color: rgba(156, 29, 29, 0.74);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#f7ce5e">
  <center>
    <h1 id="title"><br>Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors!</h1>

    <button class="button" id="play">Play</button><button class="button" id="info">Info</button>
    <center><button class="button" id="back"> Back</button>
      <p class="p" id="rock"><br>Rock: Can beat Scissors. <br>Loses to Paper.</p>
      <p class="p" id="paper"><br>Paper: Can beat Rock. <br>Loses to Scissors.</p>
      <p class="p" id="scissors"><br>Scissors: Can beat paper. <br>Loses to Rock.</p>


      <p class="p" id="ChooseAnOption">Choose an Option (you can use keyboard keys)</p>
      <button class="button" id="r">Rock (R)</button><button class="button" id="p">Paper (P)</button><button class="button" id="s">Scissors (S)</button>
    </center>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```